# Godot Light2D as an area light instead of point?

Tags: light, godot, gdscript

I notice that all Light2D nodes are emanating from a single point, even if the image being used is wide and solid. Is there a way to have a light be emitted from the entire area of the sprite and not just from a single point?

When I have "day light", I want it to light the whole level evenly. Or if I have a large spotlight I want it to feel like a giant beam instead of a single point.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> When I have "day light", I want it to light the whole level evenly.

Instead of using Light2D for this purpose, directional lighting in 2D is best simulated using a custom shader or the CanvasModulate node. That is, until Godot 4.0 is released with [built-in support for 2D directioal lights](https://godotengine.org/article/godots-2d-engine-gets-several-improvements-upcoming-40).

> Or if I have a large spotlight I want it to feel like a giant beam instead of a single point.

Unlike 3D lights, 2D lights don't make a distinction between omni and spot lights. Use a texture that looks like a spotlight (viewed from above), such as a "cone" with a 45 degree angle.

Comment: I think the 4.0 directional light is closest to what I’m lookin for.

Comment: Using different textures in light2d does not change its origination point. It always emanates from a single point no matter what texture. My texture could be solid white and if the emanation point is to the top right of an object with normal maps, it only lights the right side. What I’m looking for is an area of emanation instead of a single point.

Comment: Area lights aren't supported, I'm afraid. They are often computationally expensive to support, especially in 3D.